# PyTorch Networks within a Model

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I would like to define a network that comprises many templates.  Below under *Network Definitions* is a simplified example where the first network definition is used as a template in the second one.  This doesn't work - when I initialise my optimiser is says that the network parameters are empty!
How should I do this properly?  The network that I ultimately want is very complicated.

**Main Function**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

myNet       = Network().cuda().train()
optimizer   = optim.SGD(myNet.parameters(), lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)
```

**Network definitions:**

```
class NetworkTemplate(nn.Module):


def __init__(self):
    super(NetworkTemplate, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 3, kernel_size=1, bias=False)
    self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(3)

def forward(self, x):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.bn1(x)

    return x

class Network(nn.Module):


def __init__(self, nNets):
    super(Network, self).__init__()

    self.nets = []
    for curNet in range(nNets):
        self.nets.append(NetworkTemplate())

    def forward(self, x):

        for curNet in self.nets:
            x = curNet(x)

        return x
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `torch.nn.Sequential`? Like `self.nets=torch.nn.Sequential(*self.nets)` after you populated `self.nets` and then call `return self.nets(x)` in your `forward` function?

If you want to do something more complicated, you can put all networks into `torch.nn.ModuleList`, however you'll need to manually take care of calling them in your `forward` method in that case (but it can be more complicated than just sequential).

Comment: Changing it with nn.Sequential now gives the error list is not a module subclass

Comment: My bad, I'd forgotten the `*` to unwrap `self.nets` when passing it to `nn.Sequential`. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: This works!  Thank you very much indeed. I will up-vote your answer.  Can you please explain the * operator.  Is this a Python thing, or is this a PyTorch thing?

Comment: No, that's python. Say you have function `my_function(a,b,c)` with three arguments. As it happens, your arguments are in a list `my_list=['hello', 'world', '!']`. You could now pass those arguments as `my_function(my_list[0], my_list[1], my_list[2])`, basically unwrapping the list yourself and passing each individually. Or you use `*`: `my_function(*my_list)`, that is much easier!